# How to define an entity with "local Option set " attribute using Dynamics 365 rest API

Tags: rest, dynamics-crm, odata, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365

I'm trying to define an entity with all of it attributes , one them is an option set , and i want to define it as a "local option set", any idea of how to do this ?

here is my http request  : (i'm using dynamics 365 v9.0 on premise ) :

```
 POST /api/data/v9.0/EntityDefinitions HTTP/1.1
    {
     "@odata.type": "Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.EntityMetadata",
     "Attributes": [
     {
     "AttributeType": "String",
      "AttributeTypeName": {
      "Value": "StringType"
     },
"Description": {
"@odata.type": "Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.Label",
"LocalizedLabels": [
{
"@odata.type": "Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.LocalizedLabel",
"Label": "",
"LanguageCode": 1033
}
]
},
"DisplayName": {
"@odata.type": "Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.Label",
"LocalizedLabels": [
{
"@odata.type": "Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.LocalizedLabel",
"Label": "new_name",
"LanguageCode": 1033
}
]
},
"IsPrimaryName": true,
"RequiredLevel": {
"Value": "None",
"CanBeChanged": true,
"ManagedPropertyLogicalName": "canmodifyrequirementlevelsettings"
},
"SchemaName": "pt_mamadoo",
"@odata.type": "Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.StringAttributeMetadata",
"FormatName": {
"Value": "Text"
},
"MaxLength": 100
},
{
"SchemaName": "new_myOptionSet",
"AttributeType": "Picklist",
"AttributeTypeName": {
"Value": "PicklistType"
},
"@odata.type": "Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.OptionSetMetadata",
"IsCustomOptionSet": true,
"SourceType": 1, 
"IsGlobal": false,
"Name": "new_MyOptionSet",
"OptionSetType": "Picklist",

"DisplayName": {
"@odata.type": "Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.Label",
"LocalizedLabels": [
{
"@odata.type": "Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.LocalizedLabel",
"Label": "my Option Set",
"LanguageCode": 1033
}
]
},
"IsCustomizable": {
"Value": true,
"CanBeChanged": true,
"ManagedPropertyLogicalName": "iscustomizable"
}
}
],
"Description": {
"@odata.type": "Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.Label",
"LocalizedLabels": [
{
"@odata.type": "Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.LocalizedLabel",
"Label": "",
"LanguageCode": 1033
}
]
},
"DisplayCollectionName": {
"@odata.type": "Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.Label",
"LocalizedLabels": [
{
"@odata.type": "Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.LocalizedLabel",
"Label": "my Entities",
"LanguageCode": 1033
}
]
},
"DisplayName": {
"@odata.type": "Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.Label",
"LocalizedLabels": [
{
"@odata.type": "Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.LocalizedLabel",
"Label": "My Entity",
"LanguageCode": 1033
}
]
},
"HasActivities": false,
"HasNotes": false,
"IsActivity": false,
"OwnershipType": "UserOwned",
"SchemaName": "new_MyCustomEntity"
}
```

and i should get "No content" status code, but i get "internal server error " whith this  Error :

```
{
"error": {
"code": "0x0",
"message": "An error occurred while validating input parameters: Microsoft.OData.ODataException: An resource with type 'Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.OptionSetMetadata' was found, but it is not assignable to the expected type 'Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.AttributeMetadata'. The type specified in the resource must be equal to either the expected type or a derived type.\r\n at Microsoft.OData.ValidationUtils.ValidateEntityTypeIsAssignable(IEdmEntityTypeReference expectedEntityTypeReference, IEdmEntityTypeReference payloadEntityTypeReference)\r\n at Microsoft.OData.ReaderValidationUtils.ResolveAndValidateTargetTypeStrictValidationEnabled(EdmTypeKind expectedTypeKind, IEdmTypeReference expectedTypeReference, IEdmType payloadType)\r\n at Microsoft.OData.ReaderValidationUtils.ResolveAndValidateNonPrimitiveTargetType(EdmTypeKind expectedTypeKind, IEdmTypeReference expectedTypeReference, EdmTypeKind payloadTypeKind, IEdmType payloadType, String payloadTypeName, IEdmModel model, Func`3 clientCustomTypeResolver, Boolean throwIfTypeConflictsWithMetadata)\r\n at Microsoft.OData.ReaderValidationUtils.ResolvePayloadTypeNameAndComputeTargetType(EdmTypeKind expectedTypeKind, Nullable`1 expectStructuredType, IEdmType defaultPrimitivePayloadType, IEdmTypeReference expectedTypeReference, String payloadTypeName, IEdmModel model, Func`3 clientCustomTypeResolver, Boolean throwIfTypeConflictsWithMetadata, Boolean enablePrimitiveTypeConversion, Func`1 typeKindFromPayloadFunc, EdmTypeKind& targetTypeKind, ODataTypeAnnotation& typeAnnotation)\r\n at Microsoft.OData.ReaderValidator.ResolvePayloadTypeNameAndComputeTargetType(EdmTypeKind expectedTypeKind, Nullable`1 expectStructuredType, IEdmType defaultPrimitivePayloadType, IEdmTypeReference expectedTypeReference, String payloadTypeName, IEdmModel model, Func`1 typeKindFromPayloadFunc, EdmTypeKind& targetTypeKind, ODataTypeAnnotation& typeAnnotation)\r\n at Microsoft.OData.ODataReaderCore.ApplyResourceTypeNameFromPayload(String resourceTypeNameFromPayload)\r\n at Microsoft.OData.JsonLight.ODataJsonLightReader.ReadResourceStart(PropertyAndAnnotationCollector propertyAndAnnotationCollector, SelectedPropertiesNode selectedProperties)\r\n at Microsoft.OData.JsonLight.ODataJsonLightReader.ReadAtResourceEndImplementationSynchronously()\r\n at Microsoft.OData.ODataReaderCore.ReadImplementation()\r\n at Microsoft.OData.ODataReaderCore.InterceptException[T](Func`1 action)\r\n at System.Web.OData.Formatter.Deserialization.ODataReaderExtensions.ReadResourceOrResourceSet(ODataReader reader)\r\n at System.Web.OData.Formatter.Deserialization.ODataResourceDeserializer.Read(ODataMessageReader messageReader, Type type, ODataDeserializerContext readContext)\r\n at System.Web.OData.Formatter.ODataMediaTypeFormatter.ReadFromStream(Type type, Stream readStream, HttpContent content, IFormatterLogger formatterLogger)",
"innererror": {
"message": "An error occurred while validating input parameters: Microsoft.OData.ODataException: An resource with type 'Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.OptionSetMetadata' was found, but it is not assignable to the expected type 'Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.AttributeMetadata'. The type specified in the resource must be equal to either the expected type or a derived type.\r\n at Microsoft.OData.ValidationUtils.ValidateEntityTypeIsAssignable(IEdmEntityTypeReference expectedEntityTypeReference, IEdmEntityTypeReference payloadEntityTypeReference)\r\n at Microsoft.OData.ReaderValidationUtils.ResolveAndValidateTargetTypeStrictValidationEnabled(EdmTypeKind expectedTypeKind, IEdmTypeReference expectedTypeReference, IEdmType payloadType)\r\n at Microsoft.OData.ReaderValidationUtils.ResolveAndValidateNonPrimitiveTargetType(EdmTypeKind expectedTypeKind, IEdmTypeReference expectedTypeReference, EdmTypeKind payloadTypeKind, IEdmType payloadType, String payloadTypeName, IEdmModel model, Func`3 clientCustomTypeResolver, Boolean throwIfTypeConflictsWithMetadata)\r\n at Microsoft.OData.ReaderValidationUtils.ResolvePayloadTypeNameAndComputeTargetType(EdmTypeKind expectedTypeKind, Nullable`1 expectStructuredType, IEdmType defaultPrimitivePayloadType, IEdmTypeReference expectedTypeReference, String payloadTypeName, IEdmModel model, Func`3 clientCustomTypeResolver, Boolean throwIfTypeConflictsWithMetadata, Boolean enablePrimitiveTypeConversion, Func`1 typeKindFromPayloadFunc, EdmTypeKind& targetTypeKind, ODataTypeAnnotation& typeAnnotation)\r\n at Microsoft.OData.ReaderValidator.ResolvePayloadTypeNameAndComputeTargetType(EdmTypeKind expectedTypeKind, Nullable`1 expectStructuredType, IEdmType defaultPrimitivePayloadType, IEdmTypeReference expectedTypeReference, String payloadTypeName, IEdmModel model, Func`1 typeKindFromPayloadFunc, EdmTypeKind& targetTypeKind, ODataTypeAnnotation& typeAnnotation)\r\n at Microsoft.OData.ODataReaderCore.ApplyResourceTypeNameFromPayload(String resourceTypeNameFromPayload)\r\n at Microsoft.OData.JsonLight.ODataJsonLightReader.ReadResourceStart(PropertyAndAnnotationCollector propertyAndAnnotationCollector, SelectedPropertiesNode selectedProperties)\r\n at Microsoft.OData.JsonLight.ODataJsonLightReader.ReadAtResourceEndImplementationSynchronously()\r\n at Microsoft.OData.ODataReaderCore.ReadImplementation()\r\n at Microsoft.OData.ODataReaderCore.InterceptException[T](Func`1 action)\r\n at System.Web.OData.Formatter.Deserialization.ODataReaderExtensions.ReadResourceOrResourceSet(ODataReader reader)\r\n at System.Web.OData.Formatter.Deserialization.ODataResourceDeserializer.Read(ODataMessageReader messageReader, Type type, ODataDeserializerContext readContext)\r\n at System.Web.OData.Formatter.ODataMediaTypeFormatter.ReadFromStream(Type type, Stream readStream, HttpContent content, IFormatterLogger formatterLogger)",
"type": "Microsoft.Crm.CrmHttpException",
"stacktrace": " at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.OData.CrmODataUtilities.ValidateInputParameters(ModelStateDictionary controllerModelState)\r\n at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.OData.EntityController.PostEntitySetImplementation(String& entitySetName, EdmEntityObject entityObject)\r\n at Microsoft.PowerApps.CoreFramework.ActivityLoggerExtensions.Execute[TResult](ILogger logger, EventId eventId, ActivityType activityType, Func`1 func)\r\n at Microsoft.Xrm.Telemetry.XrmTelemetryExtensions.Execute[TResult](ILogger logger, XrmTelemetryActivityType activityType, Func`1 func)\r\n at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )\r\n at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass10.<GetExecutor>b__9(Object instance, Object[] methodParameters)\r\n at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 arguments, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()\r\n at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()\r\n at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__2.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()\r\n at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__1.MoveNext()"
}
}
}
```

Comment: try the payload like here: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/dynamics-365-customer-engagement/issues/601

Answer (score 0):

here is the solution :

```
{
    "@odata.type": "Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.EntityMetadata",
    "Attributes": [
        {
            "AttributeType": "String",
            "AttributeTypeName": {
                "Value": "StringType"
            },
            "Description": {
                "@odata.type": "Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.Label",
                "LocalizedLabels": [
                    {
                        "@odata.type": "Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.LocalizedLabel",
                        "Label": "",
                        "LanguageCode": 1033
                    }
                ]
            },
            "DisplayName": {
                "@odata.type": "Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.Label",
                "LocalizedLabels": [
                    {
                        "@odata.type": "Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.LocalizedLabel",
                        "Label": "new_name",
                        "LanguageCode": 1033
                    }
                ]
            },
            "IsPrimaryName": true,
            "RequiredLevel": {
                "Value": "None",
                "CanBeChanged": true,
                "ManagedPropertyLogicalName": "canmodifyrequirementlevelsettings"
            },
            "SchemaName": "pt_mamadoo",
            "@odata.type": "Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.StringAttributeMetadata",
            "FormatName": {
                "Value": "Text"
            },
            "MaxLength": 100
        },
        {
            "IsPrimaryName": false,
            "SchemaName": "new_myoptionsetkk",
            "AttributeType": "Picklist",
            "AttributeTypeName": {
                "Value": "PicklistType"
            },
            "@odata.type": "Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.PicklistAttributeMetadata",
            "SourceType": 0,
            "RequiredLevel": {
                "Value": "None",
                "CanBeChanged": true,
                "ManagedPropertyLogicalName": "canmodifyrequirementlevelsettings"
            },
            "IsGlobalFilterEnabled": {
                "Value": false,
                "CanBeChanged": true,
                "ManagedPropertyLogicalName": "canmodifyglobalfiltersettings"
            },
            "DisplayName": {
                "@odata.type": "Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.Label",
                "LocalizedLabels": [
                    {
                        "@odata.type": "Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.LocalizedLabel",
                        "Label": "my Optijjjj on Set",
                        "LanguageCode": 1033
                    }
                ]
            },
            "Description": {
                "@odata.type": "Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.Label",
                "LocalizedLabels": [
                    {
                        "@odata.type": "Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.LocalizedLabel",
                        "Label": "",
                        "LanguageCode": 1033
                    }
                ]
            },
            "OptionSet": {
                "IsGlobal": false,
                "OptionSetType": "Picklist"
            }
        }
    ],
    "Description": {
        "@odata.type": "Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.Label",
        "LocalizedLabels": [
            {
                "@odata.type": "Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.LocalizedLabel",
                "Label": "",
                "LanguageCode": 1033
            }
        ]
    },
    "DisplayCollectionName": {
        "@odata.type": "Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.Label",
        "LocalizedLabels": [
            {
                "@odata.type": "Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.LocalizedLabel",
                "Label": "my Entities",
                "LanguageCode": 1033
            }
        ]
    },
    "DisplayName": {
        "@odata.type": "Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.Label",
        "LocalizedLabels": [
            {
                "@odata.type": "Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.LocalizedLabel",
                "Label": "My Entity",
                "LanguageCode": 1033
            }
        ]
    },
    "HasActivities": false,
    "HasNotes": false,
    "IsActivity": false,
    "OwnershipType": "UserOwned",
    "SchemaName": "new_MyCustomEntityii"
}
```